# Having issues adding ephemeral storage to an AWS EBS instance running Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance

I am having problems adding ephemeral storage into my existing EBS backed instance. I have a small instance running on 8GB EBS root-device, and I would like to add ephemeral storage into this instance and run it as a medium instance.

The procedure I have tried which did not work for me:

1) Took a snapshot from the instance EBS volume.

2) Registered new AMI based on the snapshot using ec2-api-tools:
*ec2-register -a x86_64 -n "My AMI with ephemeral storage" --kernel <AKI-ID> --root-device-name "/dev/sda1" -b "/dev/sda1=<SNAP-ID>:8:true:standard" -b "/dev/sdc=ephemeral1"*

3) Launched new medium instance with the new AMI I just created:
 *ec2-run-instances <AMI-ID> -t m1.medium --kernel <AKI-ID> -k <MY_KEY_NAME> -g default -b "/dev/sdc=ephemeral1"*

4) SSH:ed into my new instance after it started up and the ephemeral storage is nowhere to be found (checked with *fdisk -l* for example). The root device is fine and correct, but eve nif trying out ephemeral0 instead of 1 did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is nothing in the API that tells you when you exceed your instance store mappings.  A medium instance can only have 1 ephemeral drive.  In fact /dev/sdc may only be able to mapped in large instances and up:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#StorageOnInstanceTypes